# How do I use _spawnvpe() with a custom PATH value?

Tags: c, windows, spawn

I've asked a related question in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969488/why-does-windows-spawn-process-sometimes-trigger-error-status-sxs-assembly-not-f) but I'm afraid its getting muddled by the complexity of the question, so, here's a very simple version:

Here's an example of calling _spawnvpe, manually passing the PATH value.

It doesn't work. It errors and will not run notepad.

Changing to _spawnv or not passing the PATH value makes it work. However, the documentation of _putenv clearly states the format for an env value is KEY=VALUE.

How do I make it work?

Please be specific, and provide either a diff or a full copy of the code below including a fix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  char *path_value;
  char buffer[4000];
  const char *env[2];
  const char *args[1];
  char *command;
  int result;
  intptr_t procHandle;

  path_value = getenv("PATH");
  sprintf(buffer, "PATH=%s", path_value);
  env[0] = buffer;
  env[1] = NULL;

  args[0] = NULL;

  int offset = 0;
  while (env[offset] != NULL) {
    printf("env %d: %s\n", offset, env[offset]);
    ++offset;
  }

  offset = 0;
  while (args[offset] != NULL) {
    printf("arg %d: %s\n", offset, args[offset]);
    ++offset;
  }

  command = "C:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe";

  procHandle = _spawnvpe(_P_NOWAIT, command, args, NULL);
  if (procHandle == -1) {
    printf("Failed to invoke command: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  }

  _cwait(&result, procHandle, 0);
  if (result != 0)
    printf("Command exited with error code %d\n", result);
}
```

Comment: Be sure to use the debug build, it gives you an assert on this code.  argv[0] cannot be NULL, it must point to the exe path.

Comment: You are not even using `env` in the `_spawnvpe` call presented here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me with the following code (only changed lines are shown):

```
...
const char *args[2];
...
args[0] = "notepad.exe";
args[1] = NULL;
...
procHandle = _spawnvpe(_P_NOWAIT, command, args, env);
...
```

Visual Studio 2010, Windows HPC Server 2008 R2.

Note that Windows searches for programs *AND* dynamic libraries in the `PATH` in contrast to most Unix systems that have separate variables for executable and library paths.

Comment: ^____^ you just made me very happy. Thanks!