# php-cgi not executing for google app engine under windows

Tags: php, windows, google-app-engine

OS: windows XP

I am getting above error message:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\ramesh.d\google_appengine>dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path="c:\php\php-cgi.exe" helloworld/
INFO     2013-05-20 16:23:55,069 sdk_update_checker.py:244] Checking for updates to the SDK.  
INFO     2013-05-20 16:23:56,285 sdk_update_checker.py:260] Update check failed: HTTP Error 404: Not Found  
WARNING  2013-05-20 16:23:56,285 api_server.py:329] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.  
INFO     2013-05-20 16:23:56,285 api_server.py:153] Starting API server at: 
INFO     2013-05-20 16:23:56,299 dispatcher.py:164] Starting server "default" running at: 
INFO     2013-05-20 16:23:56,299 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: 
ERROR    2013-05-20 16:23:59,168 php_runtime.py:199] The PHP runtime is not available because: "c:\php\php-cgi.exe -v" returned an error [-1072365564]
```

Comment: The error seems to be with your setup. What do you get when you execute: c:\php\php-cgi.exe -v

Comment: Related: [Why does windows spawn process sometimes trigger error STATUS_SXS_ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10969488/367456) and[STATUS_SXS_ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND (0xc0150004) - Find out which DLL is unable to load?](http://superuser.com/q/597405/63279).

Answer (score 1):

I am look for solution and found that:

in file ..\gae\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\php_runtime.py 
line 138 and 165 should be: 
env=os.environ)

if you put after line 156 new line:
print version 
you will get the result

but i do not knew what to do next

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug for Windows XP SP3 users. See https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9382 for more information and progress on a fix.

Answer (score 0):

That is a problem with python/google dev-server on your windows platform. The environment is not getting set and then PHP can not be executed having problems loading DLLs it needs.

When you execute `"c:\php\php-cgi.exe -v"` in your standard environment you should not have that error.

You should also see a msgbox you need to click OK on telling about the error-code 0xC0150004.

I am not aware of a solution for that for now, you probably want to file a bugreport for the dev-server. I don't know if this has been already reported even.