# LoadLibrary fails with ERROR_SXS_CANT_GEN_ACTCTX (the dll depends on VS2005 CRT 8.0.50727.4053)

Tags: winapi, dll, loadlibrary, side-by-side

I have a third-party DLL that is built with Visual Studio 2005, which I use in a project that is built with Visual Studio 2008. This DLL depends on VS2005 CRT, version 8.0.50727.4053.

On Windows 7 it works, but on Vista and XP LoadLibrary fails with a side by side error. The is from the Event Viewer:

> Activation context generation failed for "C:\MyLibrary.dll". Dependent
>   Assembly
>   Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.4053"
>   could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

I've tried copying `msvcm80.dll`,`msvcp80.dll`,`msvcr80.dll` from `x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_none_d08d7da0442a985d` on my computer to the same directory as the DLL, but LoadLibrary still fails and the same error is in the Event Viewer.

This is the output from sxstrace.exe:

```
=================
Begin Activation Context Generation.
Input Parameter:
    Flags = 0
    ProcessorArchitecture = x86
    CultureFallBacks = en-US;en
    ManifestPath = C:\MyDir\MyLibrary.dll
    AssemblyDirectory = C:\MyDir\
    Application Config File = 
-----------------
INFO: Parsing Manifest File C:\MyDir\MyLibrary.dll.
    INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is (null).
    INFO: Reference: Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.4053"
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.4053".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: Find publisher policy at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_policy.8.0.microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4016_none_5169e8e10f4ca52d.manifest
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT\8.0.50727.4053__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\MyDir\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\MyDir\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\MyDir\Microsoft.VC80.CRT\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\MyDir\Microsoft.VC80.CRT\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    ERROR: Cannot resolve reference Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.4053".
ERROR: Activation Context generation failed.
End Activation Context Generation.
```

Comment: You need to download and run the appropriate vcredist.  [This question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913543/why-installing-vcredist-x86-exe-doesnt-fix-sidebyside-error-when-i-develop-an-e) have lots of details.

Comment: I forgot to mention I had already tried installing the redistributable, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you install the right one?  As explained in the link I gave, there are lots to choose from.

Comment: I had no idea it needs to be specific. I just followed [the first result](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3387) from Google. Where do I find the right one?

Comment: You need the redistributable that corresponds to VS2005.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: There are loads of them!  I think [this is the right one](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14431).  [More details here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582844/vcredist-x86-dll-and-version-8-0-50727-4053).

Comment: @arx Thanks! The link you gave me works! Could you post is as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Did you try copying vcomp80.dll? It would be nice to avoid having to install redistributable packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install a redistributable package for VS2005.  Unfortunately, there are several of them for different service pack levels, security fixes and so on.

In general, to find the one you want Google the version number of the DLL that isn't loading ([8.0.50727.4053](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%228.0.50727.4053%22) in this case).

You'll probably find a [link to the right package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14431).

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=3387).